# How do I use the Account_Partner_Business api

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to use this API: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account_Partner_Business/getObject

Any calls result in

`SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception): Object does not exist to execute method on. (SoftLayer_Account_Partner_Business::getObject)`

which I assume indicates that I need an input parameter, although the API doc is not explicit on this.

If I pass in my account ID retrieved from using this api: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_account/getObject

I get this result:

`SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_ObjectNotFound): Unable to find object with id of '1314767'.`

What is the correct parameter to the Account_Partner_Business/getObject call and how do I find it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use this method:

- [SoftLayer_Account::getBusinessPartner](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getBusinessPartner)

Rest request:   `https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getBusinessPartner`

Replace: **$user** and **$apiKey** with your own credentials

It will return a response, from which the id property should be use to call [SoftLayer_Account_Partner_Business::getObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account_Partner_Business/getObject)

Rest request:

```
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account_Partner_Business/12345/getObject
```

Note: **12345** is the id from the response above

Comment: Thanks Ruber, in this case SoftLayer_Account::getBusinessPartner returns an empty string... what does that indicate? Is there some further setup needed on the account?

Comment: The empty response means that you don't have any Business Partner attached to your account, you can submit a ticket to SoftLayer, if you need further assistance with it